# why does this stop after the space

Tags: c++

I need some help checking if the string is a space and then shifting it by one char in the Alphabet I can get the first word but not any after the space.

```
string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnogqrstuvwxyz ";

cout << "Enter your string > " << flush;

cin >> OldString;

int Length = OldString.length();

for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++) {

    if(OldString[i] == Alphabet[26]){

        NewString = NewString + Alphabet[26] ;
        cout << "string found" << endl;
    }
        else {
        Result = Alphabet.find(OldString[i], 0);

        cout << Result << endl;

        NewString = NewString + Alphabet[Result + 1];
    }

}
```

Comment: `cin >> OldString;` only reads up to the first whitespace it finds, and then leaves the rest of your input in `cin`'s buffer. If you want to read an entire line at a time, take a look at [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: thank you so much. I've been baning me head against a wall for the past half hour.

Comment: _I've been baning me head against a wall for the past half hour._ It would be a joy if I could solve all my programming issues in half an hour...

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is looking for the end of input string by searching for the first whitespace in the string.

You should rather use `std::getline` instead.

So your code is going to look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string OldString;

string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnogqrstuvwxyz ";

cout << "Enter your string > " << flush;

std::getline(std::cin, OldString);

int Length = OldString.length();

for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++) {

    if(OldString[i] == Alphabet[26]){

        NewString = NewString + Alphabet[26] ;
        cout << "string found" << endl;
    }
        else {
        Result = Alphabet.find(OldString[i], 0);

        cout << Result << endl;

        NewString = NewString + Alphabet[Result + 1];
    }

}
```